# Custom Deserializer GSON

Tags: json, jsp, gson, deserialization

I have been stumped on this topic for 2 days now, and cant seem to find what I need.

I have a class as follows:

```
public class myClass {

private String name;
private ArrayList<String> arr1;
private ArrayList<String> arr2;
}
```

I am posting json via jQuery ajax to a jsp file that needs to fill an array list of myClass for further processing later. 

The JSON looks like this:

```
[{"name":"myName","arr1":["foo","bar","blahh"],"arr2":["foo","bar","blahh"]},
 {"name":"myName2","arr1":["foo","bar","blahh"],"arr2":["foo","bar","blahh"]}]
```

I tried to make a custom deserializer, but all of my attempts have been in vain.  
This is my current function:

```
     json = request.getParameter("myStuff");
     Gson gson = new Gson();
 Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<myClass>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<myClass> myClassList= new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

UPDATE:  sorry,  I forgot to clearly state what I am asking.  
I have 2 questions that are related:
1.  Do I need to use a deserializer?
2.  If yes, what is wrong with the one I have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code and JSON you posted serializes and deserializes as expected for me, without any custom deserialization.  I don't see anything wrong.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<myClass>>() {}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<myClass> myClassList= new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), listType);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(myClassList));
  }
}

class myClass
{
  private String name;
  private ArrayList<String> arr1;
  private ArrayList<String> arr2;
}
```

Is this not what you're trying to achieve?  Are you sure that the value of `json` received from `request.getParameter("myStuff")` is what you said it is?

Comment: Thanks.  I think it was because I forgot java.lang.reflect.Type, but I am not sure because I retyped it.  It works now.